# Configuration.Save method throws Unauthorized access error when the config file is placed in redirected folder

Tags: c#, redirect, configuration-files, configurationmanager, roaming-profile

I have implemented a winform application. I store the user settings for the application in the config file using the Configuration class.I store the exe along with the config file under the folder

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local

This works fine in normal case, but I am facing problem in cases where user has redirected Appdata folder to some server address.In that case I get the exception:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

I found some similar questions here but none of them have any satisfactory answers.I tried to delete the config file before running the Configuration.Save command but that gives the exception:

> The configuration file has been changed by another program.

So, how do I solve this problem.
Here is my code to Update the config file:

```
string exePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)), @"Local\<folder name>\<exe file name>");
Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
if (configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key] != null)
{
    configFile.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
}
if (param)
{
    configFile.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
}
configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Here is the stack trace for the exception:

```
at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType
 type, String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation, SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl, GenericAcl dacl)    
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String
 name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object
 exceptionContext)    
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String
 name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext) 
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String
 name, AccessControlSections includeSections)    
at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String
 fullPath)    
at System.IO.File.SetAccessControl(String path, FileSecurity fileSecurity)    
at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateTemplateAttributes(String source, String destination)    
at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.DuplicateFileAttributes(String source, String destination)    
at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String
filename, Boolean success)    
at  System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String
streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)    at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)    
at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)    
at
 System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)    
at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String
streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)    
at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename,
ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)    
at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)    
at UtilityClasses.ConfigurationHandler.UpdateConfigFile(String key, String value, Boolean param)
```

Comment: I think that the problem is that the user with which application runs just doesn't have permission for that path

Comment: @S.Petrosov the user has full permissions, and I am able to create and modify xml files at this location.

Comment: Ok. Let's try the following. Turn on sharing of that folder and try again

Comment: @S.Petrosov It is working for shared folder.

Comment: @S.Petrosov I tested it on the same machine as the shared folder and also from different machine.It worked in both the cases.

Comment: sharing is easy solution for this because if not you need to use credentials and pass authorization for connecting to network paths

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem @vk

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar expierience with changing a configuration file stored on a network share using `ConfigurationManager`.

It truns out that the `Configuration.Save` initially creates a temp file in the same location with the *desired access* set to **Write DAC** (Write Directory Access Control).

[image]

It even says so in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration.save?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> When 'Creator Owner' is listed in the ACL (Access Control List) of the
>   directory containing the configuration file, the current user of Save
>   becomes the new owner of the file and inherits the permissions granted
>   to 'Creator Owner'. This results in an elevation of privileges for the
>   current user and a removal of privileges for the previous owner.

The only workaround I could find in my environment was to copy the config to local directory, alter the file locally and then copy it back.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve this problem:
1. Share network folder so that it does not autorization for users of the same network.
2. Use user credentials to pass authorization and connect to network path.

Comment: But it does not seem to be a connection problem, as I also create and modify many xml and text files at the same path.And they don't give any problem.Only the config file is giving problems.

Comment: I have also added stack trace for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Workarounds

1. Check for a specific user's attribute on shared folder. it may have missing WriteExtended attribute.
2. Check creator of shared folder which inherits all permissions from creator.
3. Check if you can change configuration of your shared folder to non c: drive folder.